# pipeline.Fit() Function Not Working in .Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I install Microsoft.ML stable version in my Web Application and doing same as this tutorial `https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet-get-started-tutorial#install`
But `var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);` this code does not throw any error or does not continue to the next step.  Moreover, I tried this same step in a console app and gave the same result.

My Code is:

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();
var reader = mlContext.Data.CreateTextReader<IrisData>(separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: true);
            IDataView trainingDataView = reader.Read("C:/Users/HACKBAL/Documents/visual studio 2017/Projects/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/Data/Test.txt");
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"))
                .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent(labelColumn: "Label", featureColumn: "Features"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);
var prediction = model.CreatePredictionEngine<IrisData, IrisPrediction>(mlContext).Predict(
                new IrisData()
                {
                    SepalLength = 3.3f,
                    SepalWidth = 1.6f,
                    PetalLength = 0.2f,
                    PetalWidth = 5.1f,
                });

            Console.WriteLine($"Predicted flower type is: {prediction.PredictedLabels}");
```

Comment: any suggestion? I have the same issue ...

Comment: This happens for me on visual studio for Mac as well. Did anyone find out what the reason is?

Comment: Same here. Interestingly task manager shows a constant 3 Mbps network activity from the app while the Fit() method is running.

Answer (score 2):

I might be a bit late, but found the cause and the solution.
After waiting for the .Fit() method to 'run' for about 30 minutes, it finally gave me the following error:

[image: Meta file could not be downloaded]

Apparently it's trying to download the ResNet model from a remote server. Why this is not documented, and why this is being done is the Fit() method is beyond me...

Anyways, the suggested solution is to download the meta file from here:
https://aka.ms/mlnet-resources/meta/resnet_v2_101_299.meta
Then copy the file to the following folder:
C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Temp\MLNET\

Once the file is copied, run your app again, it should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use .NET Core SDK, not .NET FrameWork.
   [Download .NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)
2. Try to use my work sample on github. [Console.Example.ML.NET](https://github.com/MorozovDamian/Console.Example.ML.NET)